# Select Value by Max Date

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table in a PostgreSQL database with data like:

```
id  customer_id   item       value     timestamp

 1  001           price       1000     11/1/2021
 2  001           price       1500     11/2/2021
 3  001           condition   good     11/3/2021
 4  002           condition   bad      11/4/2021
 5  002           condition   good     11/5/2021
 6  002           price       1000     11/6/2021
 7  001           condition   good     11/7/2021
 8  001           price       1400     11/8/2021
 9  002           price       1500     11/9/2021
10  001           condition    ok      11/10/2021
11  002           price       1600     11/11/2021
12  002           price       1550     11/12/2021
```

From this table, I want to query the latest value by date and convert it to a table as below.

```
customer_id   price   condition
   001        1400      ok
   002        1550     good
```

To get this kind of table I tried with this below query, but it did not work well when there are too much data. (Operation like ***Min*** and ***Max*** to text and number)

I tested this in pgAdmin 4:

```
SELECT customer_id,
MAX (Case WHEN item='price' THEN value END) price,
MAX (Case WHEN item='condition' THEN value END) condition

FROM table_name GROUP BY customer_id
```

I want to query the value by the latest date updated data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relational design might be improved. It's an anti-pattern to mix different types of data in the same column.

While stuck with the given setup, two subqueries with `DISTINCT ON` and a `FULL OUTER JOIN` do the job:

```sql
SELECT customer_id, p.value AS price, c.value AS condition
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (customer_id)
          customer_id, value
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  item = 'condition'
   ORDER  BY customer_id, timestamp DESC
   ) c
FULL JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (customer_id)
          customer_id, value
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  item = 'price'
   ORDER  BY customer_id, timestamp DESC
   ) p USING (customer_id)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4aa930d572b5a010928dc05c5380ec5f)*

See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

This assumes `timestamp` to be defined `NOT NULL`, or you'll want `NULLS LAST`.

Depending on undisclosed cardinalities and value distribution, there may be (much) faster query variants.
If there is a `customer` table with distinct `customer_id`, (much) faster query styles become possible.

These partial, multicolumn indexes would be perfect to make it fast in any case:

```sql
CREATE INDEX tbl_condition_special_idx ON tbl (customer_id, timestamp DESC, value) WHERE item = 'condition';
CREATE INDEX tbl_price_special_idx     ON tbl (customer_id, timestamp DESC, value) WHERE item = 'price';
```

See:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Comment: It works. Thank you. 
By the way, is there any shorter query since in the example question I just used only two values under ***Item*** column? 
Actually, I may need to query to create multiple columns.

Comment: @Yan: Depending on *exact* table definition, cardinalities, data distribution and the existence of a `customer` table, there may be simpler / more elegant / (much) faster queries ... If you need that, start a new question and provide everything as instructed here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info You can always link to this one for context, and you can drop a comment here to get my attention.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT X.CUSTOMER_ID,X.PRICE,X.CONDITION
 FROM
 (
      SELECT A.CUSTOMER_ID,A.PRICE,A.CONDITION,
       ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY A.CUSTOMER_ID ORDER BY A.TIMESTAMP DESC)XCOL
  FROM YOUR_TABLE A
 )X WHERE X.XCOL=1
```

Could you please try if the above is suitable for you

Comment: May I know what are the X and A for? Where should the table_name be put?

Comment: @Yan: `X` and `A` are [*table aliases*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES). But this query doesn't do what you ask for.