# Query Value by Max Date in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I already asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70107727/select-value-by-max-date/70107818#70107818) but there contained less information about my question. So, I create a new question with more information.

Here is the sample table that I have. Each row contains the filled data by the user at every time. So that the **timestamp** column will not be **null** through the whole table. There may be unrecorded value under **item**, if the user didn't fill. The **id** is the auto-generated column for each record.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (id int, customer_id text, item text, value text, timestamp timestamp);    
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
(1, '001', 'price', '1000', '2021-11-01 01:00:00'),
(2, '001', 'price', '1500', '2021-11-02 01:00:00'),
(3, '001', 'price', '1400', '2021-11-03 01:00:00'),
(4, '001', 'condition', 'good', '2021-11-01 01:00:00'),
(5, '001', 'condition', 'good', '2021-11-02 01:00:00'),
(6, '001', 'condition', 'ok', '2021-11-03 01:00:00'),
(7, '001', 'feeling', 'sad', '2021-11-01 01:00:00'),
(8, '001', 'feeling', 'angry', '2021-11-02 01:00:00'),
(9, '001', 'feeling', 'fine', '2021-11-03 01:00:00'),
(10, '002', 'price', '1200', '2021-11-01 01:00:00'),
(11, '002', 'price', '1600', '2021-11-02 01:00:00'),
(12, '002', 'price', '2000', '2021-11-03 01:00:00'),
(13, '002', 'weather', 'sunny', '2021-11-01 01:00:00'),
(14, '002', 'weather', 'rain', '2021-11-02 01:00:00'),
(15, '002', 'price', '1900', '2021-11-04 01:00:00'),
(16, '002', 'feeling', 'sad', '2021-11-01 01:00:00'),
(17, '002', 'feeling', 'angry', '2021-11-02 01:00:00'),
(18, '002', 'feeling', 'fine', '2021-11-03 01:00:00'),
(19, '003', 'price', '1000', '2021-11-01 01:00:00'),
(20, '003', 'price', '1500', '2021-11-02 01:00:00'),
(21, '003', 'price', '2000', '2021-11-03 01:00:00'),
(22, '003', 'condition', 'ok', '2021-11-01 01:00:00'),
(23, '003', 'weather', 'rain', '2021-11-02 01:00:00'),
(24, '003', 'condition', 'bad', '2021-11-03 01:00:00'),
(25, '003', 'feeling', 'fine', '2021-11-01 01:00:00'),
(26, '003', 'weather', 'sunny', '2021-11-03 01:00:00'),
(27, '003', 'feeling', 'sad', '2021-11-03 01:00:00')
;
```

To see clearly, I order the above table by *id* and *timestamp*. It doesn't matter.

- We are using Postgresql Version: ***PostgreSQL 9.5.19***
- The actual table contains over 4 million rows
- The **item** column contains over 500 distinct items, but don't worry. I will use 10 items at most for a query. In the above table, I used only 4 items.
- We also have another table called **Customer_table** with a unique Customer_id containing customers' general information.

From the above table, I want to query the data to create a table with the latest date updated data as below. I will use 10 items at most for a query so that there may be 10 columns.

```
customer_id  price  condition  feeling   weather .......(there may be other columns from item column)
   002        1900    null      fine      rain
   001        1400     ok       fine      null
   003        2000    bad       sad       sunny
```

This is the query that I get from [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70108091/10829328), but I asked only for two **item**.

```
SELECT customer_id, p.value AS price, c.value AS condition
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (customer_id)
          customer_id, value
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  item = 'condition'
   ORDER  BY customer_id, timestamp DESC
   ) c
FULL JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (customer_id)
          customer_id, value
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  item = 'price'
   ORDER  BY customer_id, timestamp DESC
   ) p USING (customer_id)
```

So, if there is any better solution please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: The canonical form of a table definition is the `CREATE TABLE` statement ***including*** all constraints. Show PK, NOT NULL etc. And disclose relevant indexes! Not amount of prose can make up for that. Also, Postgres 9.5 has reached EOL Feb. 2021. Upgrade to a current version! There have been major improvements for big tables. There is even new functionality like `WITH TIES` that might be applicable to your case.

Comment: Also crucial: the rough number of rows per customer (min/max/avg) - for relevant items of course, as the rest can be excluded cheaply. And the number of distinct customers: `SELECT count(*) FROM Customer_table;` And: Do you query for all customers at once of for a selection? If so, what selection exactly?

Comment: There is some more information like customer_type or location, etc. in `customer_table`.  So, we query the customer form `customer_table` by filtering, and join two tables (`customer_table` and the table that I asked for query) to form the desired table.

Comment: `we query the customer form customer_table by filtering` The customer? You mean  a single customer? It makes all the difference if that's one or few or many or all customers per query.

Comment: Sorry, my mistakes. We query customers from `customer_table` by filtering *customer_type* or *location* etc to perform analysis on that user. Then we query from the above huge table by *item names* under **item** column that we want to analyze. Then we join or do other operations as we needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try other approaches using `row_number` to generate a value to filter your data on the most recent data. You may then aggregate on customer id with the max value for a case expression filtering your records based on the desired row number `rn=1` (we will order by descending) and item name.

These approaches are less verbose and based on the results online seem to be more performant. Let me know how replicating this in your environment works in the comments.

You may use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to compare this approach to the current one. The results in the online environment provided:

**Current Approach**

```
| Planning time: 0.129 ms                                                                                                      
| Execution time: 0.056 ms
```

**Suggested Approach 1**

```
| Planning time: 0.061 ms                                                                                                 
| Execution time: 0.070 ms
```

**Suggested Approach 2**

```
| Planning time: 0.047 ms                                                                                                 
| Execution time: 0.056 ms
```

**NB.** You may use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to compare these approaches in your environment which we cannot replicate online. The results may also vary on each run. Indexes and early filters on the `item` column are also recommended to improve performance.

---

**Schema (PostgreSQL v9.5)**

**Suggested Approach 1**

```
SELECT
    t1.customer_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t1.item='condition' THEN t1.value END) as conditio,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t1.item='price' THEN t1.value END) as price,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t1.item='feeling' THEN t1.value END) as feeling,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t1.item='weather' THEN t1.value END) as weather
FROM (
    SELECT
        * ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY customer_id,item
            ORDER BY tbl.timestamp DESC
        ) as rn
    FROM
        tbl 
    -- ensure that you filter based on your desired items
    -- indexes on item column are recommended to improve performance
) t1
WHERE rn=1
GROUP BY
   1;
```

| customer_id | conditio | price | feeling | weather |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | ok | 1400 | fine |  |
| 002 |  | 1900 | fine | rain |
| 003 | bad | 2000 | sad | sunny |

---

**Suggested Approach 2**

```
SELECT
    t1.customer_id,
    MAX(t1.value) FILTER (WHERE  t1.item='condition')  as conditio,
    MAX(t1.value) FILTER (WHERE  t1.item='price')  as price,
    MAX(t1.value) FILTER (WHERE  t1.item='feeling')  as feeling,
    MAX(t1.value) FILTER (WHERE  t1.item='weather')  as weather
    
FROM (
    SELECT
        * ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY customer_id,item
            ORDER BY tbl.timestamp DESC
        ) as rn
    FROM
        tbl 
    -- ensure that you filter based on your desired items
    -- indexes on item column are recommended to improve performance
) t1
WHERE rn=1
GROUP BY
   1;
```

| customer_id | conditio | price | feeling | weather |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | ok | 1400 | fine |  |
| 002 |  | 1900 | fine | rain |
| 003 | bad | 2000 | sad | sunny |

---

**Current Approach with EXPLAIN ANALYZE**

```
EXPLAIN(ANALYZE,BUFFERS)
SELECT customer_id, p.value AS price, c.value AS condition
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (customer_id)
          customer_id, value
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  item = 'condition'
   ORDER  BY customer_id, timestamp DESC
   ) c
FULL JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (customer_id)
          customer_id, value
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  item = 'price'
   ORDER  BY customer_id, timestamp DESC
   ) p USING (customer_id);
```

| QUERY PLAN |
| --- |
| Merge Full Join (cost=35.05..35.12 rows=1 width=128) (actual time=0.025..0.030 rows=3 loops=1) |
| Merge Cond: (tbl.customer_id = tbl_1.customer_id) |
| Buffers: shared hit=2 |
| -> Unique (cost=17.52..17.54 rows=1 width=72) (actual time=0.013..0.014 rows=2 loops=1) |
| Buffers: shared hit=1 |
| -> Sort (cost=17.52..17.53 rows=3 width=72) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=5 loops=1) |
| Sort Key: tbl.customer_id, tbl."timestamp" DESC |
| Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 25kB |
| Buffers: shared hit=1 |
| -> Seq Scan on tbl (cost=0.00..17.50 rows=3 width=72) (actual time=0.004..0.006 rows=5 loops=1) |
| Filter: (item = 'condition'::text) |
| Rows Removed by Filter: 22 |
| Buffers: shared hit=1 |
| -> Materialize (cost=17.52..17.55 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.010..0.013 rows=3 loops=1) |
| Buffers: shared hit=1 |
| -> Unique (cost=17.52..17.54 rows=1 width=72) (actual time=0.010..0.012 rows=3 loops=1) |
| Buffers: shared hit=1 |
| -> Sort (cost=17.52..17.53 rows=3 width=72) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=10 loops=1) |
| Sort Key: tbl_1.customer_id, tbl_1."timestamp" DESC |
| Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 25kB |
| Buffers: shared hit=1 |
| -> Seq Scan on tbl tbl_1 (cost=0.00..17.50 rows=3 width=72) (actual time=0.001..0.003 rows=10 loops=1) |
| Filter: (item = 'price'::text) |
| Rows Removed by Filter: 17 |
| Buffers: shared hit=1 |
| Planning time: 0.129 ms |
| Execution time: 0.056 ms |

---

**Suggested Approach 1 with EXPLAIN ANALYZE**

```
EXPLAIN(ANALYZE,BUFFERS)
SELECT
    t1.customer_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t1.item='price' THEN t1.value END) as price,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t1.item='condition' THEN t1.value END) as conditio
    
FROM (
    SELECT
        * ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY customer_id,item
            ORDER BY tbl.timestamp DESC
        ) as rn
    FROM
        tbl 
    where item IN ('price','condition')
) t1
WHERE rn=1
GROUP BY
   1;
```

| QUERY PLAN |
| --- |
| GroupAggregate (cost=17.58..17.81 rows=1 width=96) (actual time=0.039..0.047 rows=3 loops=1) |
| Group Key: t1.customer_id |
| Buffers: shared hit=1 |
| -> Subquery Scan on t1 (cost=17.58..17.79 rows=1 width=96) (actual time=0.030..0.040 rows=5 loops=1) |
| Filter: (t1.rn = 1) |
| Rows Removed by Filter: 10 |
| Buffers: shared hit=1 |
| -> WindowAgg (cost=17.58..17.71 rows=6 width=104) (actual time=0.029..0.038 rows=15 loops=1) |
| Buffers: shared hit=1 |
| -> Sort (cost=17.58..17.59 rows=6 width=104) (actual time=0.028..0.030 rows=15 loops=1) |
| Sort Key: tbl.customer_id, tbl.item, tbl."timestamp" DESC |
| Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 26kB |
| Buffers: shared hit=1 |
| -> Seq Scan on tbl (cost=0.00..17.50 rows=6 width=104) (actual time=0.003..0.008 rows=15 loops=1) |
| Filter: (item = ANY ('{price,condition}'::text[])) |
| Rows Removed by Filter: 12 |
| Buffers: shared hit=1 |
| Planning time: 0.061 ms |
| Execution time: 0.070 ms |

---

**Suggested Approach 2 with EXPLAIN ANALYZE**

```
EXPLAIN(ANALYZE,BUFFERS)
SELECT
    t1.customer_id,
    MAX(t1.value) FILTER (WHERE  t1.item='price')  as price,
    MAX(t1.value) FILTER (WHERE  t1.item='condition')  as conditio
    
FROM (
    SELECT
        * ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY customer_id,item
            ORDER BY tbl.timestamp DESC
        ) as rn
    FROM
        tbl 
    where item IN ('price','condition')
) t1
WHERE rn=1
GROUP BY
   1;
```

| QUERY PLAN |
| --- |
| GroupAggregate (cost=17.58..17.81 rows=1 width=96) (actual time=0.029..0.037 rows=3 loops=1) |
| Group Key: t1.customer_id |
| Buffers: shared hit=1 |
| -> Subquery Scan on t1 (cost=17.58..17.79 rows=1 width=96) (actual time=0.021..0.032 rows=5 loops=1) |
| Filter: (t1.rn = 1) |
| Rows Removed by Filter: 10 |
| Buffers: shared hit=1 |
| -> WindowAgg (cost=17.58..17.71 rows=6 width=104) (actual time=0.021..0.030 rows=15 loops=1) |
| Buffers: shared hit=1 |
| -> Sort (cost=17.58..17.59 rows=6 width=104) (actual time=0.019..0.021 rows=15 loops=1) |
| Sort Key: tbl.customer_id, tbl.item, tbl."timestamp" DESC |
| Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 26kB |
| Buffers: shared hit=1 |
| -> Seq Scan on tbl (cost=0.00..17.50 rows=6 width=104) (actual time=0.003..0.008 rows=15 loops=1) |
| Filter: (item = ANY ('{price,condition}'::text[])) |
| Rows Removed by Filter: 12 |
| Buffers: shared hit=1 |
| Planning time: 0.047 ms |
| Execution time: 0.056 ms |

---

[View working demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pUxdF5NPD3Z7Avf6Z6qxar/4)

Comment: Thank you for helping me. It works and is exactly what I am asking for. I will use **Suggested Approach 1**, but I will add *where item IN ('price','condition')* as you explained in **Suggested Approach 1 with EXPLAIN ANALYZE**.

Comment: @Yan: Note that query plans based on a hand full of sample rows are hardly relevant. Test with your original big table to get valid results.

Answer (score 1):

You operate on a **big table**. You mentioned 4 million rows, obviously growing. While querying for ...

- **all customers**
- **all items**
- with **few  rows** per `(customer_id, item)`
- with **narrow rows** (small row size)

... [ggordon's solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70114916/939860) with `row_number()` are great. And short, too.
The **whole table** has to be processed in a **sequential scan**. Indices won't be used.
But prefer "**Approach 2**" with the modern aggregate `FILTER` syntax. It's clearer and faster. See performance tests here:

- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27572/3684)

#### Approach 3: Pivot with `crosstab()`

`crosstab()` is typically faster, especially for more than a few items. See:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
   $$
   SELECT customer_id, item, value
   FROM  (
      SELECT customer_id, item, value
           , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id, item ORDER BY t.timestamp DESC) AS rn
      FROM   tbl t
      WHERE  item = ANY ('{condition,price,feeling,weather}')  -- your items here ...
      ) t1
   WHERE  rn = 1
   ORDER  BY customer_id, item
   $$
 , $$SELECT unnest('{condition,price,feeling,weather}'::text[])$$  -- ... here ...
   ) AS ct (customer_id text, condition text, price text, feeling text, weather text);  -- ... and here ...
```

#### Approach 4: `LATERAL` Subqueries

If one or more of the criteria listed at the top do not apply, the above queries fall off quickly in performance.

For starters, only max 10 of "500 distinct items" are involved. That's max ~ 2 % of the big table. That alone should make one of the following queries (much) faster in comparison:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM  (SELECT customer_id FROM customer) c
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT value AS condition
   FROM   tbl t
   WHERE  t.customer_id = c.customer_id
   AND    t.item = 'condition'
   ORDER  BY t.timestamp DESC
   LIMIT  1
   ) AS t1 ON true
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT value AS price
   FROM   tbl t
   WHERE  t.customer_id = c.customer_id
   AND    t.item = 'price'
   ORDER  BY t.timestamp DESC
   LIMIT  1
   ) AS t2 ON true
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT value AS feeling
   FROM   tbl t
   WHERE  t.customer_id = c.customer_id
   AND    t.item = 'feeling'
   ORDER  BY t.timestamp DESC
   LIMIT  1
   ) AS t3 ON true
--  ... more?
```

About `LEFT JOIN LATERAL`:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

The point is to get a query plan with relatively few index(-only) scans to replace the expensive sequential scan on the big table.
Requires an applicable **index**, obviously:

```
CREATE INDEX ON tbl (customer_id, item);
```

Or better (in Postgres 9.5):

```
CREATE INDEX ON tbl (customer_id, item, timestamp DESC, value);
```

In Postgres 11 or later, this would be better, yet:

```
CREATE INDEX ON tbl (customer_id, item, timestamp DESC) INCLUDE (value);
```

See [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/190151/3684) or [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/207938/3684) or [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/indexes-index-only-scans.html).

If only few items are of interest, partial indices on those items would be even better.

#### Approach 5: Correlated Subqueries

```sql
SELECT c.customer_id
     , (SELECT value FROM tbl t WHERE t.customer_id = c.customer_id AND t.item = 'condition' ORDER BY t.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) AS condition
     , (SELECT value FROM tbl t WHERE t.customer_id = c.customer_id AND t.item = 'price'     ORDER BY t.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) AS price
     , (SELECT value FROM tbl t WHERE t.customer_id = c.customer_id AND t.item = 'feeling'   ORDER BY t.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) AS feeling
     , (SELECT value FROM tbl t WHERE t.customer_id = c.customer_id AND t.item = 'weather'   ORDER BY t.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) AS weather
FROM   customer c;
```

Not as versatile as `LATERAL`, but good enough for the purpose. Same index requirements as approach 4.

Approach 5 will be **king of performance in most cases**.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=c4998ae889846464958f425a3e12ba19)*

Improving your relational design and/or upgrading to a current version of Postgres would go a long way, too.

Comment: Thank you so much for your multiple suggestions. You gave me many ideas on my questions. This makes me feel that there are multiple solutions to fetch the data and what I have to do is to find the best match for my problems. These solutions help me a lot.